# How to run SpringBoot app as non-root user on Debian?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, permissions

Using Debian 10.

I am trying to run SpringBoot *app.jar* application i made on a server as non-root user.

I created new user called *SpringBootApp*.

Application is supposed to run on 443 port.

I changed owned of this .jar file to *SpringBootApp* and changed permissions to 770 with these commands:

```
chown springbootapp app.jar

chmod 770 app.jar
```

However while trying to start application as this user, I get this exception: `java.net.BindException: "permission denied"`. What other permissions do i need to change to run it as non-root user?

The way i run application: `java -jar app.jar`

Output:

```
Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'webServerStartStop'; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at ispf.webapp.WebappApplication.main(WebappApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[app.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:229) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.WebServerStartStopLifecycle.start(WebServerStartStopLifecycle.java:43) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-context-5.3.12.jar!/:5.3.12]
        ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:238) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:282) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:213) ~[spring-boot-2.5.6.jar!/:2.5.6]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1075) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:234) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Permission denied
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:552) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.netBind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:336) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:294) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:271) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:226) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1208) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1294) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:614) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1072) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.54.jar!/:na]
        ... 28 common frames omitted
```

With a root user, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which port is your application configured to run on?

The BindException is suggesting it to be a [privileged port](https://www.w3.org/Daemon/User/Installation/PrivilegedPorts.html).
If this is the case, you could try to set it to another port by command line argument (see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port#command-line)

Comment: Is configured to run on 443 and i want to keep it that way.

Comment: You can't, it's that simple. For everything below 1024 you'll need root access. In production environments one would use a reverse proxy to have the Spring application start without root (e.g. on port 8080) and still listen to e.g. 443.

Comment: For example configuring apache web server as reverse proxy and forward it to port 8080 where spring boot aplication is configured to listen to? So apache web server will also need root access, but spring boot app not?

Comment: Exactly. Most people would default to nginx, haproxy or traefik, but Apache should work aswell.